# It Runs First Time while loading the frame but when i choose the secound item it gives me error

Tags: java, awt, jcombobox

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        jComboBox1.revalidate();
        jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
        jComboBox3.removeAllItems();
        jComboBox4.removeAllItems();
        String b1=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String bb=this.branch;
        String y1=this.year;
            if(y1!=null){
                String[] b=y1.split(";");
                System.out.println(y1);
                System.out.println(b1);
               int size=b.length;
               System.out.println(size);
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                if(b[i].matches("(?i).*"+b1+".*")){
                    System.out.println(b[i]);
               jComboBox2.addItem(b[i].replaceAll(":","").replaceAll(b1.toLowerCase(), "")); 
            jComboBox2ActionPerformed( evt);
            }}}
    }
```

It Runs First Time while loading the frame but when i choose the secound item it gives me error

Comment: And what is the error? Can you display the stacktrace in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you apply `removeAllItems` then there is no item in combo-box

so [`getSelectedItem`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/javax/swing/JComboBox.java#JComboBox.getSelectedItem%28%29) internally use the [`ComboBoxModel getSelectedItem`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.java#ComboBoxModel.getSelectedItem%28%29) function which states

> The selected item or null if there is no selection

although [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem()) doesn't state anything about returning null

solution : you get `null` and `toString()` in `null` cause you the nullpointer exception so make sure you have some items when you call `getSelectedItem` or put a nullity check

```
String b1=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()!=null ? jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString(): "";
```